Get Java Source code from Quarkus Docker Image
Given the docker image of a quarkus application, how do I get to the java source code?
Quarkus Version 2.12.0.Final

For JVM-based languages and compiled languages in general, a Docker image won't usually contain the original source.  You'd need a decompiler or better to check out the original source tree from source control.

Firstly create a container of the image
docker container create imagename

Docker creates a containerid for that image which can be retrieved using
docker ps -a

Export that container to a tar and then unzip the tar as follows:
docker export containerid | tar -xvf - -C /path/to/destination

After this, go to the destination folder.
Here search for the application-name.jar file, you will find it in one of the folders.
In my case it was in /home/jboss/app
Then one just needs to extract the files of the jar file
jar xf application-name.jar

